# How to sort 3 items in a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm trying to make a sort function that sorts a list of 3 or less elements, but pattern matching is confusing me.

```
intCMP :: Int -> Int -> Ordering
intCMP a b | a == b =EQ
           | a < b = LT
           | otherwise = GT

 sort3 :: Ord a => (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
 sort3 _ [] = []
 sort3 _ [a] = [a]
 sort3 cmp [a,b] = if cmp a b == LT then
                    [a,b]
                   else
                   [b,a]
 sort cmp [a,b,c] = [a,b,c]
```

but i keep getting this error

*Main> sort3 intCMP [1,1,1]

*** Exception: fun.hs:(7,1)-(12,23): Non-exhaustive patterns in function sort3

Comment: Why not use `compare` rather than a custom `intCMP`?

Comment: You don't need to use `cmp`, you could just write `if a < b then`

Answer (score 4):

What you thought was your last clause is actually a new function named `sort` (rather than `sort3`). Turning on `-Wall` will help you notice this kind of error.

Comment: I've been staring at this for 2 hours, thanks for the catch